# How to build a DTO based on multiple DTOs?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, nestjs, dto

I have several DTOs for the user

First:

```
export class UserProfileContactDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  readonly email: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsPhoneNumber('ua')
  readonly phone: string;
}
```

Second:

```
export class UserProfileDataDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  readonly name: string;

  @ApiProperty({ required: false })
  @IsString()
  readonly lastname: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEnum(userGenderEnum)
  readonly gender: userGenderEnum;
}
```

I would like to get a third DTO based on these DTOs:

```
export class UserCreateDto extends UserProfileDataDto, UserProfileContactDto{  

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @Matches(/((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/, {
    message: 'password too weak',
  })
  readonly password: string;
}
```

But I can't use extends for multiple classes and interfaces don't work for me because I'm using the class-validator library. 
How can you solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since TS does not support multiple inheritance and you cannot use interfaces, you could solve this using composition for the contact data (it requires you to change the interface though):

```
export class UserProfileDataDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  readonly name: string;

  @ApiProperty({ required: false })
  @IsString()
  readonly lastname: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEnum(userGenderEnum)
  readonly gender: userGenderEnum;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly contactData: UserProfileContactDto;
}
```

Then you can extend from this class as you did for the `UserCreateDto`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My main class - **UserCreateDto** actually should extends not two classes, but five or more - **UserProfileDataDto, UserProfileContactDto, UserAddressDto, UserOrder, UserLogin**. It would be possible to describe all this inside **UserCreateDto**, but I need to use some groups of fields separately.

Comment: That is, to update the address, I need **UserAddressDto**. I could use **Partial<UserCreateDto>** but there will be too many unnecessary non-address fields. Perhaps there is another way to organize this?

Comment: I'd still use composition in that case. E.g. for the address add a new property `address` which is of type `UserAddressDto` to the `UserCreateDto`.

Comment: thanks! I misunderstood what you mean. Now I understand what you mean. I hope it works out that way. If not, I will write about my difficulties